# Improving Jasmine test output for array comparisons

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I want replace this test code:

```
expect(events.length).toEqual(2);

expect(events[0].item).toEqual("A");
expect(events[0].newIndex).toEqual(0);
expect(events[0].type).toEqual(CollectionChangeType.Insert);

expect(events[1].item).toEqual("D");
expect(events[1].oldIndex).toEqual(2);
expect(events[1].type).toEqual(CollectionChangeType.Remove);
```

...with the shorter form (which is actually more thorough in my case)...

```
expect(events).toEqual([
    CollectionChange.insert("A", "A", 0),
    CollectionChange.remove("D", "D", 2)
]);
```

However the output in the case of errors is too hard to read.

> Expected [ { type : 0, item : 'A', itemId : 'A', newIndex : 0, oldIndex : -1 }, { type : 2, item : 'D', itemId : 'D', newIndex : -1, oldIndex : 3 } ] to equal [ { type : 0, item : 'A', itemId : 'A', newIndex : 0, oldIndex : -1 }, { type : 2, item : 'D', itemId : 'D', newIndex : -1, oldIndex : 2 } ].

Is there a way to customise this output? For example, I would be happy with:

```
Array items differ at indices:

[1] expected { type: 2, item: 'D', itemId: 'D', newIndex: -1, oldIndex: 3 }
    but saw  { type: 2, item: 'D', itemId: 'D', newIndex: -1, oldIndex: 2 }
```

Can I modify the logic in case of array comparison to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own jasmine matcher that has a more verbose message. [See this link for details](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Matchers)

I made a simple version in jasmine 1.3 that could get you started.

```
describe("example", function ()
{
    beforeEach(function ()
    {
        this.addMatchers({

            arrayComparison: function (expected)
            {
                var actual = this.actual;
                this.message = function() { return "Array items differ at indices:\n\n[1] expected " + expected + "\n but saw " + actual; }
                return this.actual == expected;
            }
        });
    });
    it("should compare arrays", function ()
        {
            var array1 = { type: 2, item: 'D', itemId: 'D', newIndex: -1, oldIndex: 3 };
            var array2 = { type: 2, item: 'D', itemId: 'D', newIndex: -1, oldIndex: 2 };
            expect(array1).arrayComparison(array2);
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a promising approach. Will investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a custom formatter to get pretty output is inconvenient, because it forces you to write a custom formatter for every test where your custom object is involved. E.g. you have to duplicate the custom formatting logic for `[{key: new MyObject() }]` and `[new MyObject()]`. It would be much more convenient if there was a way to specify how `MyObject` is serialized.

This can be done via the `jasmineToString` method. If this function is present on the function, then Jasmine will print its return value instead of recursively processing the object. This works in all versions of Jasmine (1.3, 2.0, 2.1, 2.3).

Here is an example (with deliberately failing tests):

```js
function MyObject(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.junk = 'bla bla'; // I do not want to see this.
}

it('should be pretty', function() {
    MyObject.prototype.jasmineToString = function() {
        return 'MyObject(' + this.id + ')';
    };
    expect([new MyObject(123)]).toBe(new MyObject('different'));
    // "Expected [ MyObject(123) ] to be MyObject(different)."
});
it('should be ugly', function() {
    MyObject.prototype.jasmineToString = undefined;
    expect([new MyObject(123)]).toBe(new MyObject('different'));
    // "Expected [ MyObject({ id: 123, junk: 'bla bla' }) ] to be ..."
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.4/jasmine.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.4/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.4/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.4/boot.js"></script>
```